# How to Create Custom Customer Attribute with only Registration time. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I want to Create Custom Customer attribute for magento 2.

Which include in admin side at Customer creation time only.

After customer Create we want to just display it on customer Edit page as in disable state. admin can't edit it after first insert just readonly mode.

How to do that?

My custom Customer attribute code:

```
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attr', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Position',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 999,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_attr')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();
```

Comment: You want to show in frontend.or else only in customer edit page at admin.@JACK

Comment: Give more details for this, If you want to disable it than customer has right to set value for this attribute while registration process ?

Comment: I want to just add attribute at admin side while customer create. At edit time i don't want it. also no need to display at frontend

Comment: Well i don't think its possible with **InsallData.php** , You can disable it by overriding customer edit form using Ui_component and make it disable.

Comment: @LazyCoder i already try that way also. if i disable for edit it also disable for create.both place use customer_index_edit.xml so it use same form for both. any other solutions are welcome.